# Display the output of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure to truncate the table whose name is passed as a parameter to the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure delete_data_from_table(table_id VARCHAR2)
is
    cursor table_cur is
        SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%' || table_id || '%';
    tab_name VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
    open  table_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH table_cur into tab_name;
        exit when table_cur%notfound;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || tab_name;
    END LOOP;
    close table_cur;
END;
```

I want to display the output of the `execute immediate` statement using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you expecting to see? Something like the text a specific  client like SQL\*Plus displays (which is from the client, not the DB)?

Comment: I want to display "Table truncated successfully" or the output of the TRUNCATE TABLE itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native output from `execute immediate` or the statement you are running. When you truncate a table in a client it will usually report something like:

```
Table truncated.
```

or

```
Table MY_TABLE truncated.
```

or similar; but those messages are generated by the client running the command, not by the database.

You can just generate whatever message you want in your procedure, e.g.:

```
...
    LOOP
        FETCH table_cur into tab_name;
        exit when table_cur%notfound;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || tab_name;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table ' || tab_name || ' truncated.');
    END LOOP;
...
```

If the truncate statement fails for any reason then it will throw an exception and it won't reach the `dbms_output` line.

For other statement types you can optionally use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to report the number of rows inserted/updated/merged/deleted to mimic what your client might show for those, but that doesn't apply for truncation.

Bear in mind though that someone else running your code might not have display of those messages enabled.